# Getting an input onclick in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to get an input when the user taps on a cell of a UITableView. That's my code:

```
import UIKit

class TableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    public var data = Array<Array<String>>()

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row][1]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("TEST")
    }

}
```

And in ViewController I have:

```
...


let tvClass = TableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tvClass.data = [["title", "name"]]
    self.tableView.dataSource = tv
    self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
}


...
```

Why am I not getting "TEST" when I click on a cell?

Comment: you missed the delegate self.tableView.delegate = self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`didSelectRowAt` is a method inside `UITableViewDelegate` so , set table delegate like this in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

and change class declaration like this

```
class TableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
```

Comment: I think you wanted to say `self.tableView.delegate = tvClass`. Right?

Comment: Thanks. Now I've added after `print(test)` this: `let test = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewTest") as! ViewTest` and then `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(test, animated: true)`. Do you know why am I getting an error?

Comment: Well, it's printing `TEST` but then it doesn't change the view. The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: make sure storyboard id is ViewTest for the viewController ViewTest

Comment: Yes it's correct but the error is still present. Why?

Comment: How can I check it? I think the problem is the hierarchy: I'm running TableView from ViewController's viewDidLoad()

Comment: print("\(self.navigationController)") if nil then this is the problem

Comment: I tried `print(self.navigationController)` and it printed `nil`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The Only missing thing is

TableViewDelegate.

As delegate tells iOS sdk to know that action is being performed.

> self.tableView.delegate = self